# Features in CodeRush Xpress for writing plugins

Tags: plugins, coderush, coderush-xpress

I am using CodeRush Xpress and found that I cannot write a plugin using IssueProvider from this [page (end of third paragraph)](http://www.drrandom.org/2009/10/07/GettingACodeRushInsideACodeRushCodeIssue.aspx). Now I am using codeProvider to write simple plugins using CodeRush Xpress.

With CodeProvider I can only show the notification with these 3 dots[image: Dots pop up when there is an error]. 
 I wanted to show the errors by

1.) Underling the code   and

2.) Providing a URL in the hint box (So that  the user can click this URL to know more about the problem).[image]

Is there a way to underline the code in coderush Xpress. And also any ways to provide links in the hint box.

Some links or some lines of code used to underline would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high-level [Code Issues](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/02/coderush-code-issues-technology-overview/) UI functionality (underlining, issue hints with links(URLs), left and right issue bars) is available in CodeRush Pro, but not CodeRush Xpress. So you won't be able to see code issues with CodeRush Xpress only.